# Scrape web form to database prior to submission

Tags: jquery, web-scraping, browser-extension

I have a customer who uses a third party application to submit data (fill in web form) which uses jQuery.

the problem is that the third party provider won't supply the data back to the customer so they can use it for other purposes. Essentially if I am to get the data the customer would have to enter it twice.

I was wondering if there was any way of collecting the data (and uploaded images) prior to the customer submitting the form to the third party. Is it possible to use a browser extension to scrape the info prior to them submitting?

I'm lost for ideas- any help would be amazing.

Comment: change the client plugin. Handle the form manually and you can do what you want with the data. Even post them later to the third party application. Vague question means vague answer ;)

Comment: thanks- I can't change the client plugin. Basically the client plugin uses is what uploads it to the listing site (third party provider) and I was hoping to avoid the need for double entry. Essentially I want to collect the info at the same time the client is entering it into the plugin.

Comment: what about posting some code then?

Comment: You could wrap it in... another form (web, console whatever) that posts the entered data to the client web form _and_ a database. If I understand correctly your current process is completely manual. What languages/platforms are you happy programming in?

Answer (score 1):

You can create web extensionand use [WebRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest) API to do get the request details when the user submit.